# Importing PyVISA via Py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe, visa

My script file test.py is:

```
try:
    from visa import *
except Exception as ex:
    print ex
    raw_input()
```

My setup.py file is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['test.py'])
```

I then run:

> python setup.py py2exe

If I then launch test.exe on my pc I see no issues but if I copy it to a new pc with no prior python installs I get:

> [Error 126] The specified module could not be found

I don't know how to get the full traceback to print. Has anyone else seen this issue?
Running Python 2.7, PyVisa 1.4. Both machines are Win7.

Comment: When I say, "copy it" I of course mean copy the entire dist folder to the new pc and then launch test.exe

Comment: When I originally saw this issue in my windows app the full traceback ended with something like: File "C:\Python27\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 340, in __init__

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "visa.pyo", line 1, in <module>
  File "pyvisa\visa.pyo", line 231, in <module>
  File "pyvisa\vpp43.pyo", line 105, in __new__
  File "pyvisa\visa.pyo", line 227, in init
  File "pyvisa\vpp43.pyo", line 758, in open_default_resource_manager
  File "pyvisa\vpp43.pyo", line 175, in __call__
  File "pyvisa\vpp43.pyo", line 141, in load_library
  File "ctypes\__init__.pyo", line 423, in __getattr__
  File "ctypes\__init__.pyo", line 353, in __init__
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was that the visa libraries that pyvisa relies on weren't installed on the test pc. These libraries don't come included with pyvisa.